# What is the trick for getting grid snapping to work?

Tags: snapping

Using Blender 2.90 now, with hopes that it might be more functional than 2.83. All I am trying to do is have objects snap to the grid when moving, rotating, and resizing them. Here are the steps I took:

1. Select the object.
2. Open Edit mode and select one of the vertices.
3. Shift-S and "Selection to Cursor"
4. Object menu > Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor
5. Open Snapping menu and select "Absolute Grid Snap"

Now, when hitting G and moving the object around, it is not snapped to anything. After all the steps above, one would think something this simple would work. What am I missing?

I have already looked over the bug reports, and someone mentioned today that since 2.79, snapping doesn't work. So perhaps I am expecting too much. Nonetheless, over 60% of the functionality I have tried (according to docs, forums, and online tutorials) either looks nothing like the screenshots or doesn't work as described. I'll do my best not to go on another diatribe. I was able to calm down yesterday and except that re-meshing objects wouldn't be possible with this tool. Having a grid snap may be an ambitious goal for Blender, but hopefully not impossible.

Comment: Did you enable the snapping icon? The magnet next to the snap menu shows blue if you have.

Comment: Why are you running an experimental build of Blender when you would appear to have very important work to do? I base this assumption on the earlier question you posted, where you indicate that you either work for or with some entity that is contemplating a purchase of Maya. If your work is serious enough to consider such a purchase, it should be serious enough to abstain from using experimental builds of Blender, which are known to be unstable. By the way, I use 2.83 and I don't have snapping issues. Don't know why you do.